# How to Fetch data from image in form of row list in Python

Tags: python, image, processing

.[image]

'1/30', 'Online Transfer to Burton R Preferred Checking XXXXXX7255 Ref'#1b047946Qf on 01/30/18', '3,000.00', '18,323.23'

Please help me how to get data in row wise, how to pre-process images in OCR.space API. Appreciate your your help.Thank You.

Comment: You can try aws textract. Its pretty simple to use and cheap as well.

Comment: @Ashwani dont you think OCR.space would enough for this task?

Comment: Haven't tried OCR.space so can't say much, but you should go with any available version of  tesseract OCR. IMO tesseract is pretty good for such tasks. Infact there is a free version named python tesseract as well. You can search for other libraries.

Comment: i did use tesseract but its accuracy is not good enough.

Comment: @Ashwani please give me code with AWS Textract in python i will test and then let you know.